# How do you constrain a generic type to be a class and support new()?

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to implement the GenericRepository pattern for a Cosmos DB Gremlin Graph API Datasource. So I have:

1. Added and verified a working [Gremlin.Linq](https://github.com/crosscutsolutions/gremlin.linq) library that interfaces w/my Cosmos Graph Database.
2. Know that in the [Generic Repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application#create-a-generic-repository) it implements `TEntity` where `TEntity` is a `class`. I have done the same.
3. I am now implementing my Generic Repository and want to use a [Generic Extension with a clause for a new()](https://github.com/crosscutsolutions/gremlin.linq/blob/5ff88cce7779746a8ce865773074870fbd58ab8a/Gremlin.Linq/Linq/Selectors/SelectorExtensions.cs#L14) so I'm getting the error. What should I do?

**Error**
The type 'typename' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'parameter' in the generic type or method 'generic'

[image]

Comment: Do you see in your screenshot, the end of the colored text in the popup, it says `where TEntity : new()`? Try adding that to _your_ class.

Comment: Side note: It is always good idea to post code as text, and explain how error explanation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0310) was not clear

Comment: @gunr2171 yes the extension expects `TEntity` to be `new()` but my `GenericRepository` needs `TEntity` to be `class`. Can you help?

Comment: This question does not have the appropriate title. The underlying question is "How do I apply the class and new() type constraints for a generic type?"

Comment: @JohnV that's not the underlying question. The question is/was as I had it, the answer/solution is to add the `new()` but only in solving the 1st question did I research to learn this. But thanks to you too for your answer.

Comment: The reason why I said it's the wrong question is because you can't "convert" a type to new() at all. That doesn't really make sense. (i.e., the vocabulary is wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allowed to apply multiple generic constraints when defining a generic type, like so:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRespository<TEntity> 
    where TEntity : class, new() //the new() constraint must come last
```

These constraints mean that in order for a type to be used with `GenericRespository<>`, it must be both a class (a reference type) **and** it must provide a public parameter-less constructor. (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint))

In practice, this means you could have a `GenericRepository<object>`, but not a `GenericRepository<int>` because int is a value-type, or `GenericRepository<Uri>` because although `Uri` is a class, it does not have a public parameter-less constructor.

```
public class GenericRespository<T> 
    where T : class, new()
{
    public T Create() => new T();
}

public class Repositories
{
    //won't compile, int is a value type;
    readonly GenericRespository<int> intRepository = new GenericRespository<int>();

    //wont compile, Uri is a class, but no public
    //parameterless constructor
    readonly GenericRespository<Uri> uriRpository = new GenericRespository<Uri>(); //no public parameterless constructor, doesn't work.
    
    //object is a class and supports new object(), so this works
    readonly GenericRespository<object> objectRepository = new GenericRespository<object>(); //works fine
}
```

These type constraints mean that your `GenericRespository<TEntity>` will be able to create new `TEntity` instances on it's own.  The real value of this is that you will be able to create your **own** classes and create a repository of them without writing any additional code.

Answer (score -3):

The correct answer is that Generics can have multiple clauses. So I was able to solve my problem simply by extending the clause (`, new()`). Now `TEntity` has to either be a `class` and a `new()` which is good for me!

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer, unless you want to really flesh it out. However, John's done a good job of that and you've accepted his answer. I'd suggest deleting this and adding it as a comment to your question.